# ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. On table

Tags: tables, line-breaking

when compiling it gave me this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

my code :

```
\scalebox{0.8}{\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
                                                                          & Actions de mise en conformité à réaliser & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Actions de\\ sensibilisation à\\ destination de\\ l’ensemble des\\ collaborateurs\\ sur des\\ thématiques\\ générales et\\ spécialisées\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{1-2}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tâches à réaliser à\\ court terme\end{tabular} &      [courtTerme]                                &                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \cline{1-2}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tâches à réaliser à\\ moyen terme\end{tabular} &       [moyenTerm]                                &                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \cline{1-2}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tâches à réaliser à long\\ terme\end{tabular}  &       [longTerm]                                 &                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
```

it's a 3x4 table with the last column merge
Can't figure why

---

*Addendum*: If the `\scalebox` directive is made to encase the `tabular` environment rather than the `table` environment, and if the `multirow`, `babel`, and `fontenc` packages are loaded with suitable options, the result is as in the following screenshot:

[image]

What should I do to keep the contents of the third column contained with the table?

Comment: you should always show a complete example, which can be compile. But you should never put a table environment inside a box or another environment.

Comment: You want to make this table fit somehow. See [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764) (possible duplicate)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of posting an addendum, in which the `\scalebox` directive is made to encase the `tabular` environment rather than the `table` environment. (The result is a table in which the contents of the third column exceed the space available to them.) Feel free to revert.

Comment: surely you must have had an earlier `not in outer par mode` error from `\scalebox{0.8}{\begin{table}[`  ? you can not have a `table` environment in a box.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the `\scalebox` sledgehammer, I wouldn't use `multirow`, and I wouldn't break the lines within various cells by hand. Instead, I'd use nested `tabular` environments and let LaTeX take care of the tedious line-breaking job.

[image]

I chose the width of the right-hand column (2.5cm) to make its overall height roughly equal to the heights of the other two columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped look
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}| P{2.5cm}|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{|P{3cm}|P{3.5cm}}
& Actions de mise en conformité à réaliser     \\ \hline
Tâches à réaliser à court terme & [courtTerme] \\ \hline
Tâches à réaliser à moyen terme & [moyenTerm]  \\ \hline
Tâches à réaliser à long terme  & [longTerm] 
\end{tabular} &
Actions de sensibilisation à destination de l’ensemble des 
collaborateurs sur des thématiques générales et spécialisées \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```